# Elegant Angular JS solution for displaying address form based on country

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I'm implementing different address forms based on country selection (as described [here](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2008/06/international-address-fields-in-web-forms.php)).

Are there any widely used directives or plugins for displaying this using Angular? Something more elegant than just using `<ng-if>` blocks? When I looked around online I couldn't find much, so I'm wondering if anyone has any pretty solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be creating several templates, one per different kind of addres and having a map that maps them to a selected country.

See plunkr as an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lemBzf2es0rlOb9uORVL?p=preview)

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="c as c for c in countries"></select>
     <div ng-include="templates[selected] || 'default' "></span>
   </body>


   <script type="text/ng-template" id="US">
      <input type="text">
   </script>


   <script type="text/ng-template" id="UK">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
   </script>


   <script type="text/ng-template" id="default">
      Unknown Country
   </script>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.templates = {
    UK: "UK",
    US: "US"
  };

  $scope.countries = [ "UK", "US", "AR" ];
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been mulling it over and this seems to be the way to go. Thanks!